# getting no properties are mapped for type using csvHelper

Tags: csvhelper

I have the following class

```
public class EventObject
{
    public int OrderID { get; private set; }
    public int DemandID { get; private set; }
    public string ExternalEventID { get; private set; }
    public int Part { get; private set; }
    public int BasedOnObjectID { get; private set; }
    public int BasedOnStateID { get; private set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; private set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; private set; }
    public int? EventID { get; private set; }

    public static IEnumerable<EventObject> LoadFromCSV(TextReader reader)
    {
        var plannedEventsToReturn = new List<EventObject>();
        var csv = new CsvReader(reader);
        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<EventObjectMap >();
        return csv.GetRecords<EventObject>().ToList();
    }
}
```

and I have created a mapping class as documentd in csvHElper

```
public sealed class EventObjectMap : CsvClassMap<EventObject>
{
    public EventObjectMap ()
    {
        Map(m => m.OrderID).Index(0);
        Map(m => m.DemandID).Index(1);
        Map(m => m.ExternalEventID).Index(2);
        Map(m => m.Part).Index(3);
        Map(m => m.BasedOnObjectID).Index(4);
        Map(m => m.BasedOnStateID).Index(5);
        Map(m => m.StartDate).Index(6).TypeConverter<OptimizationDateTimeConverter>();
        Map(m => m.EndDate).Index(7).TypeConverter<OptimizationDateTimeConverter>();
        Map(m => m.EventID).Index(8).TypeConverter<NullableIntConverter>();
    }
}
```

when I hit the line

```
return csv.GetRecords<EventObject>().ToList();
```

i get an exception

> no properties are mapped for type

Comment: I get this even with public properties

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found the problem .. the properties had a private set .. 
they need to be public like this..

```
public int OrderID { get; set; }
public int DemandID { get; set; }
public string ExternalEventID { get; set; }
public int Part { get;  set; }
public int BasedOnObjectID { get; set; }
public int BasedOnStateID { get; set; }
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
public int? EventID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer is working correctly, but there is another way to solve this problem as the following

```
CsvConfiguration configuration = new CsvConfiguration
{
   IgnorePrivateAccessor = true,
}

CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(/*your TextReader*/, configuration);
```

Documentation

> Gets or sets a value indicating if a private member should be read from and written to. True to include private members, otherwise false. Default is false.

**NOTE** You could face the same problem even if you have `internal` property

```
internal int OrderID { get; set; }
```

---

**For the newer version of the library** it seems that the property changed its name to be `IncludePrivateMembers`

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to fix this:

```
csv.Configuration.MemberTypes = CsvHelper.Configuration.MemberTypes.Fields;
```

The case for me may be slightly different, in that I am using fields instead of properties, but it was the same error message so...

Answer (score 1):

You can now use the `IncludePrivateMembers` property.

```
using CsvHelper;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Xunit;

namespace UseIncludePrivateMembers
{
    public class Stub
    {
        public double Value1 { get; private set; }
        public double Value2 { get; private set; }
    }

    public class Tests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test()
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Value1,Value2");
                writer.WriteLine("5,6");
                writer.Flush();
                stream.Position = 0;

                csv.Configuration.IncludePrivateMembers = true;
                var record = csv.GetRecords<Stub>().First();

                Assert.Equal(5, record.Value1);
                Assert.Equal(6, record.Value2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```